# How do you edit the group creation steps for non admin users in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

In my buddypress setup, I have the groups component enabled. I also have the bp docs, bbpress, invite anyone plugins installed.

Currently when I create a group regardless who I am logged in as, I get prompt the following steps in the following order:

1. group-details
2. group-settings
3. forum
4. resources
5. invite anyone

I would like to preserve all these steps for the admin keymaster users but I would like to disable the forum and resources steps. How can I achieve this?

I have attempted to use the following code at the top of the create.php within the groups directory:

```
global $bp;
if(!bbp_is_user_keymaster()){
    unset( $bp->groups->group_creation_steps['forum'] );
    unset( $bp->groups->group_creation_steps['resources'] );
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work so well as the page still redirects to the forum step after group-settings. The forum page does appear to be empty with back and next buttons being visible. If click on the next button, I get a page error and if I click on the back button, I get redirected to the invite-anyone step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at `do_action( 'groups_custom_create_steps' );` and actually use `remove_action();`. You will need to investigate the functions/methods that are used and hooked on `groups_custom_create_steps`.
Thus you will be able to remove empty screens of steps as well.

Also, it's better to place your code into [bp-custom.php](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/), and not in theme files.

Comment: i created bp-custom.php and put my original code in there but i am getting the same result.
remove_action() is not a valid function.

Comment: Here is a doc for `remove_action()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: You should find by yourself functions that uses `add_action( 'groups_custom_create_steps' ...` and remove them.